# if parts of two columns match in a file, copy row and move to new file

Tags: bash

I have a blastn output file with tens of thousands of rows. I'm only interested in rows where part of the query sequence ID does not match with part of the subject sequence ID, which I'd like to put into a new text file. Here is an excerpt of the massive output file for which I want to extract information from, as an example:

```
qseqid qlen qstart qend sseqid slen sstart send evalue bitscore length pident nident mismatch gaps
OFAS003927-RA-EXON03_Acanthocephalini_Acanthocephala_alata_CMF_0025_S10_L005_UQ_trinity_assembled   744 121 679 OFAS003927-RA-EXON03_Anisoscelini_Anisoscelis_flavolineatus_CMF_0018_S7_L005_UQ_trinity_assembled   557 1   557 0   832 562 93.594  526 28  8
OFAS003927-RA-EXON03_Acanthocephalini_Acanthocephala_alata_CMF_0025_S10_L005_UQ_trinity_assembled   744 155 650 OFAS003927-RA-EXON03_Placoscelini_Plaxiscelis_limbata_CMF_0072_S29_L005_UQ_trinity_assembled    820 327 819 0   808 496 96.169  477 16  3
OFAS003927-RA-EXON03_Acanthocephalini_Acanthocephala_alata_CMF_0025_S10_L005_UQ_trinity_assembled   744 222 686 OFAS003927-RA-EXON03_Anisoscelini_Leptoscelis_tricolor_CMF_0079_S32_L005_UQ_trinity_assembled   465 1   465 0   793 465 97.419  453 12  0
OFAS003927-RA-EXON03_Acanthocephalini_Acanthocephala_alata_CMF_0025_S10_L005_UQ_trinity_assembled   744 429 635 OFAS003927-RA-EXON03B_Clavigrallini_Clavigralla_sp_CMF_0335_S81_L005_UQ_trinity_assembled   655 1   207 4.30E-87    316 207 94.203  195 12  0
OFAS003927-RA-EXON03_Acanthocephalini_Acanthocephala_alata_CMF_0025_S10_L005_UQ_trinity_assembled   744 531 629 OFAS003927-RA-EXON07_Mictini_Anoplocnemis_sp_CMF_0052_S20_L005_UQ_trinity_assembled 668 1   99  9.92E-39    156 99  94.949  94  5   0
OFAS007459-RA-EXON03_Acanthocephalini_Acanthocephala_alata_CMF_0025_S10_L005_UQ_trinity_assembled   696 1   696 OFAS007459-RA-EXON03_Acanthocephalini_Acanthocephala_alata_CMF_0025_S10_L005_UQ_trinity_assembled   696 1   696 0   1286    696 100 696 0   0
OFAS007459-RA-EXON03_Acanthocephalini_Acanthocephala_alata_CMF_0025_S10_L005_UQ_trinity_assembled   696 1   696 OFAS007459-RA-EXON03_Acanthocephalini_Acanthocephala_declivis_CMF_0069_S26_L005_UQ_trinity_assembled    1060    332 1025    0   1212    696 98.132  683 11  2
OFAS007459-RA-EXON03_Acanthocephalini_Acanthocephala_alata_CMF_0025_S10_L005_UQ_trinity_assembled   696 1   696 OFAS007459-RA-EXON03_Acanthocephalini_Acanthocephala_thomasi_CMF_0028_S13_L005_UQ_trinity_assembled 814 50  745 0   1147    698 96.418  673 21  4
OFAS007459-RA-EXON03_Acanthocephalini_Acanthocephala_alata_CMF_0025_S10_L005_UQ_trinity_assembled   696 1   695 OFAS007459-RA-EXON03_Acanthocephalini_Acanthocephala_confraterna_CMF_0123_S44_L005_UQ_trinity_assembled 1313    578 1274    0   1131    699 95.994  671 22  6
```

qseqid = query sequence ID

sseqid = subject sequence ID

What should be matching is the OFAS#-RA-EXON# between the two ID's for each row. When this isn't the case, e.g., the 4th and 5th row, I want to extract the entire row and place into a new text file. I know some regex pattern will need to be employed, but how to indicate columns and search on a per row basis isn't clear to me.

Comment: Those are multiple spaces delimiting each column, right? And I assume spaces can't appear inside the values?

Comment: Also, if the `OFAS#-RA-EXON#` string can't appear outside of the two columns you're concerned about, don't even bother with columns, just use `^(OFAS\d{6}-RA-EXON\d{2}_).*\1` and invert that match.

Comment: Columns are delimited by tabs and spaces cannot appear inside the values. I'll give your second comment a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work with GNU Awk :

```
tail -n+2 input.txt | awk  '{ if( substr($1,0,21) !=  substr($5,0,21)) { print $0 } }'
```

Regards!

Comment: This didn't quite work; it outputted rows in which the two ID columns do not completely match. However, I'm only wanting to match based the OFAS#-RA-EXON# string. All the other characters after in the sequence IDs should not be considered.

Comment: @MikeF I have edited the code. It was referencing columns 1 and 2 when it should have been 1 and 5. Also, I increased the substring length to 21